# CA-Markov unavailability in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cellular-automata

Under QGIS plugin,  I can't find CA-Markov plugin.  How do I install it in the latest QGIS version?

Comment: Did you check with the plugin contributor? What does that plugin do? Maybe its functionality was incorporated into QGIS?